# Call to await GetFileAsync() never returns and app hangs in WinRT app

Tags: c#, file-io, windows-8, windows-runtime, async-await

I'm attempting to load and read a settings file on application launch, and about 90% of the time, the `await GetFileAsync("filename.xml");` never returns, thus, hanging the application.

About a quarter of the time, if I step through the code, it'll actually return and read the file.

Here's a very simplified version of the code:

App.xaml.cs:

```
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    FileLoader.Load().Wait();

    // File-load dependent stuff
}
```

FileLoader.cs:

```
public async static Task Load()
{
    StorageFolder folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    StorageFile file;
    bool fileExists = true;

    try
    {
        // The following line (often) never returns
        file = await folder.GetFileAsync("filename.xml");
    {
    catch
    {
        fileExists = false;
    }

    // Do stuff with loaded file
}
```

If I watch the Output window in Visual Studio, after awhile of waiting I get `"The thread '<No Name>' (0x30c) has exited with code 0 (0x0)."`

Does anyone have any idea of what's happening here?

Comment: You're blocking the UI thread as far as I can see by calling `Wait`. That's a really bad idea. Heck, that might even be what's causing the problem.

Comment: I think Jon's exactly right - any chance you can mark OnLaunched as async and then await the Load() call instead?  If you can't, then another approach might be to have Load take an action to execute after the load has finished and then run the action at the end (or, of course, you can use ContinueWith on the task that Load() returns just like you would before async/await :)

Comment: You were both right, Jon and James. Thank you very much for the input! I was originally using `Wait` because I didn't realize you could add `async` to an overridden method, and I didn't know that `OnLaunched` was running on the UI thread. Removing `Wait` and adding `async` to `OnLaunched` fixed it! I wish I could mark your comments as the answer.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

By default, when you `await` a `Task` that has not yet completed, the method resumes on a captured context (in this case, the UI context).

So, here's why your code is failing:

- `OnLaunched` calls `Load` (within the UI context).
- `Load` awaits. This causes the `Load` method to return an incomplete task and schedule its completion for later. This continuation is scheduled for the UI context.
- `OnLaunched` blocks on the task returned from `Load`. This blocks the UI thread.
- `GetFileAsync` eventually completes, and attempts to run the continuation for `Load`.
- The continuation for `Load` waits for the UI thread to be available so it can execute in the UI context.
- At this point, `OnLaunched` is waiting for `Load` to complete (blocking the UI thread by doing so), and `Load` is waiting for the UI thread to be free. Deadlock.

These best practices avoid this situation:

1. In your "library" `async` methods, use `ConfigureAwait(false)` whenever possible. In your case, this would change `await folder.GetFileAsync("filename.xml");` to `await folder.GetFileAsync("filename.xml").ConfigureAwait(false);`.
2. Don't block on `Task`s; it's `async` all the way down. In other words, replace `Wait` with `await`.

For more information:

- [Await, and UI, and deadlocks! Oh, my!](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/01/13/10115163.aspx)
- My [`async`/`await` intro post](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html), which includes a brief description of how `Task` awaiters use `SynchronizationContext` and introduces some best practices.
- The [Async/Await FAQ](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/12/10293335.aspx), which goes into more detail on the contexts.
- This [MSDN forum post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/async/thread/269172a3-adb9-4b5e-9ac1-8b67ff920177).
- Stephen Toub [demos this deadlock](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/BUILD/BUILD2011/TOOL-829T), and [so does Lucian Wischik](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lucian/archive/2012/03/29/talk-async-part-1-the-message-loop-and-the-task-type.aspx).

**Update, 2012-07-13:** Incorporated this answer [into a blog post](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

Comment: Excellent answer! Thank you very much for the detailed explanation of what's happening and the extensive list of reference articles. This makes everything much clearer.

Comment: This was perfect. This saved me so much grief it was unbelievable.

Comment: I wish MS to be dead. They are definitely seek people due to providing such crazy things. Why the hell they just didn't left old-fashion threads and sync primitives?! Morons.

Comment: @AlekDepler: [Asynchronous programming is the opposite of multithreading](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html). While you can "fake" *some* async programming using threads, you cannot *always* use threads to solve asynchronous programming requirements.

Comment: I can and I do. "Fake" is the wheels that MS invent every year. For now, the only requirement I need in WPF is simple threads. Tired...

Comment: absolutely agree, msft should burn in hell with its bunch of async paradigms, new one each year. It looks like a bad movie - money are spend, people hate it, and producer spends millions again for reviews, ads, movie about movie to make us believe his movie was great. So many articles, lessons, videos about Tasks. Ok, but why should I spend hours to make this piece of sh*t to read local files?! F**k!! Local files, Carl!